# how to implement pbewithmd5andtripledes algorithm with golang

Tags: go, encryption

I want to Implemente encryption algorithm pbewithmd5andtripledes with golang, I can not found the appropriate method

I found a repo, but it is PBEWithMD5AndDES
https://github.com/pineda89/PBEWithMD5AndDES

Comment: _PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES_ is an Oracle proprietary extension to support longer keys using MD5 for key derivation and TripleDES for encryption. [Here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBECipherCore.java.html#281) you can find a Java implementation of the key derivation as blueprint. Note that MD5 and TripleDES are deprecated and should only be used for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the libraries code at this [line](https://github.com/pineda89/PBEWithMD5AndDES/blob/b0fd1cac6d3926521759ff67caa5c3fed230f3e3/PBEWithMD5AndDES.go#L28) It uses library `crypto/des` library. `crypto/des` also provides api for [tripleDes](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.16.6:src/crypto/des/cipher.go;l=73). You might want to fork the library and change the implementation suitable to you.